# How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

I would like to take a string

```
var a = "http://example.com/aa/bb/"
```

and process it into an object such that

```
a.hostname == "example.com"
```

and

```
a.pathname == "/aa/bb"
```

Comment: In case you're working on the current URL, you can access `hostname` and `pathname` directly from the `location` object.

Comment: what about "lastPathPart"?

Comment: Not regex but the Python Module tldextract does this exactly: https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract

Answer (score 384, accepted):

```
var getLocation = function(href) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = href;
    return l;
};
var l = getLocation("http://example.com/path");
console.debug(l.hostname)
>> "example.com"
console.debug(l.pathname)
>> "/path"
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a cross-browser compatible solution?

Comment: href is a special DOM attribute type with those additional URI-like properties on it. Very interesting!

Comment: It should be noted that, while this may help/answer the original poster, this answer will only work for people doing JS work in a browser, since it relies on the DOM to do its work.

Comment: Another example of simplicity, alongside ingenuity.

Comment: Does not work in IE if the href is relative. l.hostname will be empty. If you're only providing full URL's then this will work.

Comment: If you need relative URL support in IE, check out Claus's answer.

Comment: This doesn't work in chrome. Anytime you pass anything invalid, you get the calling domain back. So if there no referrer it looks like a self referral.

Comment: Even with absolute URLs, IE (tested in IE 11) behaves differently from Chrome and Firefox. IE's `pathname` removes the leading slash, while the other browsers do not. So you'll end up with `/path` or `path`, depending on your browser.

Comment: here is my usl: `www.example.com/contact#test` how can I get `test` ?

Comment: @Sajad, if you are looking for a front-end solution, and the url in question is the url of the page you are on, `location.hash` is all of you need. Else, look at @Rems answer below.

Comment: as @AdamBatkin noted, without DOM this won't work.. which means it's a no-go in Service Workers as well.

Comment: In IE11, having a username in the href will cause all these property reads to throw security errors.

Example: "http://www.example.com" will work just fine.  But "http://username@www.example.com" or "http://username:password@www.example.com" will make any attempt to reference one of the other properties of the anchor element (example: hash) to fail and throw an obnoxious error.

Comment: Check docs for Browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname

Comment: IE11 appends the SSL port to the `host` property `"google.com:443"`, may cause inconsistencies

Comment: This answer is outdated. Can you please change the accepted answer to be the one that uses the new URL API?

Comment: This caused me a lot of problems with internet explorer since I used the result for a regex. Here is a fix to make it coherent across the browsers: `var pathname 
 = l.pathname.replace(/(\/)?/, '/');`

Comment: @freddiefujiwara I didn't edit, but consider to add the fix in the answer

Comment: If you dont need to manipulate host or protocol, just use origin

Answer (score 619):

The modern way:

```
new URL("http://example.com/aa/bb/")
```

Returns an object with properties `hostname` and `pathname`, along with [a few others](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#instance_properties), most notably, `port` and `searchParams` (prepared instance of [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)).

Note that `host` contains both `hostname`+`port`,

but `hostname` only contains the domain (and **not the port**).

The first argument is a relative or absolute URL; if it's relative, then you need to specify the second argument (the base URL). For example, for a URL relative to the current page:

```
new URL("/aa/bb/", location)
```

In addition to browsers, [this API is also available in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api) since v7, through `require('url').URL`.

Comment: The only problem is now you have to parse whether it's relative or absolute yourself. IMO this should just be handled by `URL`. Maybe we can get it into the spec? :P

Comment: The relative part is a separate argument rather than concatenation. eg: new URL( path, baseURL )

Comment: Experimental technology: IE doens't support this! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @cwouter: It does work in Edge however, which replaces IE

Comment: this is the way to do it, edge is already 3 versions on top of ie so it doesn't matter

Comment: @justingordon: The `URL` class is a Web standard, so non-browsers aren't required to implement it. However, recent versions of Nodejs do provide an identical library, [`require('url').URL`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api)

Comment: This does not get you the domain. It will return the protocol as part of the domain.

Comment: @AndroidDev: How did you use it? `new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript").host`?

Comment: @rvighne I feel like it's important to note that there is no support for this on IE11 and below https://caniuse.com/#search=url

Comment: The fact that JavaScript doesn't have a built-in way to parse URLs that works on browsers or servers is pretty sad...

Comment: @Skitterm it's pretty ironic that this is the case.

Comment: This should be way higher, a great answer that works in any environment (or at least for my purposes lol)!  And most importantly, it's modern.

Comment: Why is this so far down? It has the most upvotes even. StackOverflow is weird nowadays.

Comment: It is better to use  try block if the URL is a variable. new URL throws catchable exception if the string is not a valid URL
try {
    url = new URL(theInputURL)
  } catch (_) {
    //catch error 
  }

Answer (score 333):

found here: https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.origin;   // => "http://example.com:3000"
```

Comment: Note that if you just want to get the parsed parts of the current browser location, the 1st two lines become `parser = location;` and all the following lines work. Tried it in Chrome and IE9 just now.

Comment: Also note that `pathname` doesn't include the leading slash in IE. Go figure. :D

Comment: For IE, use "/" + parser.pathname

Comment: Warning: it will return `http:` even if you pass just `domain.com` to href (without any protocol). I wanted to use this to check if the protocol was missing, and if so I could add it, but it assumes http: so was unable to use it for this purpose.

Comment: The hostname actually includes the protocol. Test on the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I tried getting the hostname today under Chrome, and it didn't include the protocol.

Comment: IE11 appends the SSL port to the `host` property `"google.com:443"`, may cause inconsistencies

Comment: @ddavidad What do you mean by "it won't work"? <a> tags, when not prefixed by a scheme, will assume that the href is a path. AFAICT, it's working as intended.

Comment: Just use origin if you need the content before the path

Comment: I reference this about once every three months.

Answer (score 137):

Here's a simple function using a regexp that imitates the `a` tag behavior.

Pros

- predictable behaviour (no cross browser issues)
- doesn't need the DOM
- it's really short.

Cons

- The regexp is a bit difficult to read

-

```
function getLocation(href) {
    var match = href.match(/^(https?\:)\/\/(([^:\/?#]*)(?:\:([0-9]+))?)([\/]{0,1}[^?#]*)(\?[^#]*|)(#.*|)$/);
    return match && {
        href: href,
        protocol: match[1],
        host: match[2],
        hostname: match[3],
        port: match[4],
        pathname: match[5],
        search: match[6],
        hash: match[7]
    }
}
```

-

```
getLocation("http://example.com/");
/*
{
    "protocol": "http:",
    "host": "example.com",
    "hostname": "example.com",
    "port": undefined,
    "pathname": "/"
    "search": "",
    "hash": "",
}
*/

getLocation("http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash");
/*
{
    "protocol": "http:",
    "host": "example.com:3000",
    "hostname": "example.com",
    "port": "3000",
    "pathname": "/pathname/",
    "search": "?search=test",
    "hash": "#hash"
}
*/
```

EDIT:

Here's a breakdown of the regular expression

```
var reURLInformation = new RegExp([
    '^(https?:)//', // protocol
    '(([^:/?#]*)(?::([0-9]+))?)', // host (hostname and port)
    '(/{0,1}[^?#]*)', // pathname
    '(\\?[^#]*|)', // search
    '(#.*|)$' // hash
].join(''));
var match = href.match(reURLInformation);
```

Comment: Doesn't work with any relative URLs. Did you follow RFC-3986 when making the regexp?

    > getLocation("//example.com/");
    null
    > getLocation("/pathname/?search");
    null
    > getLocation("/pathname/");
    null
    > getLocation("relative");
    null

Comment: I like how this does not use the DOM, but gregers has a good point. It would be nice if this can handle relative paths. It would require to use window.location (an a element) to fill in the blanks and adding code. In that case, the method would become hypocritical. Unless there is an alternative, not sure how this can be solved perfectly.

Comment: Added the href key with original url, this provides consistency on that return object with the dom implementation.

Comment: If someone need to parse relative URLs here is the updated regexp:
/^(?:(https?\:)\/\/)?(([^:\/?#]*)(?:\:([0-9]+))?)([\/]{0,1}[^?#]*)(\?[^#]*|)(#.*|)$/

Answer (score 107):

```
var loc = window.location;  // => "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash"
```

returns the currentUrl.

If you want to pass your own string as a url ([doesn't work in IE11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)):

```
var loc = new URL("http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash")
```

Then you can parse it like:

```
loc.protocol; // => "http:"
loc.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
loc.hostname; // => "example.com"
loc.port;     // => "3000"
loc.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
loc.hash;     // => "#hash"
loc.search;   // => "?search=test"
```

Answer (score 66):

freddiefujiwara's answer is pretty good but I also needed to support relative URLs within Internet Explorer.  I came up with the following solution:

```
function getLocation(href) {
    var location = document.createElement("a");
    location.href = href;
    // IE doesn't populate all link properties when setting .href with a relative URL,
    // however .href will return an absolute URL which then can be used on itself
    // to populate these additional fields.
    if (location.host == "") {
      location.href = location.href;
    }
    return location;
};
```

Now use it to get the needed properties:

```
var a = getLocation('http://example.com/aa/bb/');
document.write(a.hostname);
document.write(a.pathname);
```

Example:

```js
function getLocation(href) {
  var location = document.createElement("a");
  location.href = href;
  // IE doesn't populate all link properties when setting .href with a relative URL,
  // however .href will return an absolute URL which then can be used on itself
  // to populate these additional fields.
  if (location.host == "") {
    location.href = location.href;
  }
  return location;
};
var urlToParse = 'http://example.com/aa/bb/',
  a = getLocation(urlToParse);
document.write('Absolute URL: ' + urlToParse);
document.write('<br />');
document.write('Hostname: ' + a.hostname);
document.write('<br />');
document.write('Pathname: ' + a.pathname);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Very clever use of relative-to-absolute URL handling. +1

Comment: Apparently not the first time a JSFiddle link died: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179964/my-jsfiddle-page-returns-404-registration-required

Comment: This worked great, however I had one update that I hope will help others.  I'm using this to check origin on a postMessage request and when the port is a default port (80 or 443), it doesn't get appended to the path.  I conditionally checked for that when creating my URL:

`var locationHost = (location.port !== '80' && location.port !== '443') ? location.host : location.hostname;`  
`var locationOrigin = location.protocol + '//' + locationHost;`

Comment: I made this comment elsewhere on a more popular variant of this solution, but as this was my favorite solution, I wanted to repeat it here.  In IE11, having a username in the href will cause all these property reads to throw security errors.

Example: "http://www.example.com" will work just fine.  But "http://username@www.example.com" or "http://username:password@www.example.com" will make any attempt to reference one of the other properties of the anchor element (example: hash) to fail and throw an obnoxious error.

Comment: fantastic solution! 

Answer (score 18):

**[js-uri](http://code.google.com/p/js-uri/)** (available on Google Code) takes a string URL and resolves a URI object from it:

```
var some_uri = new URI("http://www.example.com/foo/bar");

alert(some_uri.authority); // www.example.com
alert(some_uri);           // http://www.example.com/foo/bar

var blah      = new URI("blah");
var blah_full = blah.resolve(some_uri);
alert(blah_full);         // http://www.example.com/foo/blah
```

Comment: thanks!!! but
I want to 
uri = new Location("http://example.com/aa/bb")
typeof(window.location) == typeof(uri)

Comment: Since window.location is a string, I don't really see how that would be possible or helpful. Why do the types need to match when you can easily convert from one to the other?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location is very nice api!! so I hope convert String to window.location object

Comment: Setting window.location changes the browser so it is not going to happen.

Comment: Hmm that's right. window.location is not a string, but can be assigned from a string. I'm not sure if that can be mimicked, I've tried assigning the prototype of location to a new uri object but that did not work.

Comment: Thank you for an opinion. 
Would you teach the source code that you tried?

Comment: Keep in mind that this has bugs in it: no IPv6 support and it breaks when an `@` is present after the hostname.

Answer (score 15):

today I meet this problem and I found: [URL - MDN Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```
var url = new URL("http://test.example.com/dir/subdir/file.html#hash");
```

This return:

```
{ hash:"#hash", host:"test.example.com", hostname:"test.example.com", href:"http://test.example.com/dir/subdir/file.html#hash", origin:"http://test.example.com", password:"", pathname:"/dir/subdir/file.html", port:"", protocol:"http:", search: "", username: "" }
```

Hoping my first contribution helps you !

Comment: Duplicate answer

Comment: Yeah but the guy at the top just update his awser in 2017, me I post it in 2016.

Comment: Ah my bad, sorry

Answer (score 13):

What about simple regular expression?

```
url = "http://www.example.com/path/to/somwhere";
urlParts = /^(?:\w+\:\/\/)?([^\/]+)(.*)$/.exec(url);
hostname = urlParts[1]; // www.example.com
path = urlParts[2]; // /path/to/somwhere
```

Comment: Try to parse something valid like `//user:password@example.com/path/x?y=z` and you will see why simple regular expression does not cut it. Now throw something invalid to it and it should bail out in predictable way, too.

Comment: Simple regex is for simple problems :) But it doesn't sound to me that url like this is unparsable by regex, it would just need few more tweaks. But I'd probably go for some library if I need something more complex and bulletroof though.

Comment: I agree with @svestka's comments above, but if you want a simple regex solution and have a trusted source (like I do) and no access to the DOM or URL() (as I'm using tabris.js) then a regex can be the way to go. Here's one that can handle the query string too `^(?:\w+\:\/\/)?([^\/]+)([^\?]*)\??(.*)$`

Answer (score 11):

```
function parseUrl(url) {
    var m = (url || sp.targetUrl()).match(/^(([^:\/?#]+:)?(?:\/\/((?:([^\/?#:]*)(?::([^\/?#:]*))?@)?([^\/?#:]*)(?::([^\/?#:]*))?)))?([^?#]*)(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$/),
        r = {
            hash: m[10] || "",                   // #asd
            host: m[3] || "",                    // localhost:257
            hostname: m[6] || "",                // localhost
            href: m[0] || "",                    // http://username:password@localhost:257/deploy/?asd=asd#asd
            origin: m[1] || "",                  // http://username:password@localhost:257
            pathname: m[8] || (m[1] ? "/" : ""), // /deploy/
            port: m[7] || "",                    // 257
            protocol: m[2] || "",                // http:
            search: m[9] || "",                  // ?asd=asd
            username: m[4] || "",                // username
            password: m[5] || ""                 // password
        };
    if (r.protocol.length == 2) {
        r.protocol = "file:///" + r.protocol.toUpperCase();
        r.origin = r.protocol + "//" + r.host;
    }
    r.href = r.origin + r.pathname + r.search + r.hash;
    return r;
};
parseUrl("http://username:password@localhost:257/deploy/?asd=asd#asd");
```

It works with both absolute and relative urls.
To handle relative path as absolute url without schema change regex to `/^((?:([^:\/?#]+:)(?:\/\/))?((?:([^\/?#:]*)(?::([^\/?#:]*))?@)?([^\/?#:]*)(?::([^\/?#:]*))?))?([^?#]*)(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$/`

Comment: `abc://username:password@example.com:123/path/data?key=value&key2=value2#fragid1`

Comment: @山茶树和葡萄树 I have updated the code to handle userinfo subcomponent properly. Thanks for your comment, I didn't notice that problem before

Comment: love this regex

Comment: nice regex! what I miss is pathname without parameters, preferable also any file separated .
I did solve that with an additional regex, so there is no urgent need, but it's just a proposition.

Comment: filename and filesuffix could be still separated too.

Comment: @Nikolay b.xxx.xx.xx.xxx.com:5388 not work, can not get hostname

Comment: @MichaelMao That's because absolute urls should always have scheme defined. Anyway I've updated regexp to handle such pseudo-absolute urls, so this is not a problem now. I have no enough time to test this regexp using wide range of urls, but I believe all should works fine.

Comment: @Nikolay very nice! One small bug, if there is a username but no password (such as "git@myhost.com"), then the hostname field will include the username, and the username field will be blank.

Comment: @Brett I've updated the code and it should work fine now

Answer (score 10):

Here is a version that I copied from https://gist.github.com/1847816, but rewritten so it's easier to read and debug. The purpose of copying the of the anchor data to another variable named "result" is because the anchor data is pretty long, and so copying a limited number of values to the result will help simplify the result.

```
/**
 * See: https://gist.github.com/1847816
 * Parse a URI, returning an object similar to Location
 * Usage: var uri = parseUri("hello?search#hash")
 */
function parseUri(url) {

  var result = {};

  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = url;

  var keys = 'protocol hostname host pathname port search hash href'.split(' ');
  for (var keyIndex in keys) {
    var currentKey = keys[keyIndex]; 
    result[currentKey] = anchor[currentKey];
  }

  result.toString = function() { return anchor.href; };
  result.requestUri = result.pathname + result.search;  
  return result;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

[Cross-browser URL parsing](https://gist.github.com/acdcjunior/9820040), works around the **relative path problem for IE** 6, 7, 8 and 9:

```
function ParsedUrl(url) {
    var parser = document.createElement("a");
    parser.href = url;

    // IE 8 and 9 dont load the attributes "protocol" and "host" in case the source URL
    // is just a pathname, that is, "/example" and not "http://domain.com/example".
    parser.href = parser.href;

    // IE 7 and 6 wont load "protocol" and "host" even with the above workaround,
    // so we take the protocol/host from window.location and place them manually
    if (parser.host === "") {
        var newProtocolAndHost = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
        if (url.charAt(1) === "/") {
            parser.href = newProtocolAndHost + url;
        } else {
            // the regex gets everything up to the last "/"
            // /path/takesEverythingUpToAndIncludingTheLastForwardSlash/thisIsIgnored
            // "/" is inserted before because IE takes it of from pathname
            var currentFolder = ("/"+parser.pathname).match(/.*\//)[0];
            parser.href = newProtocolAndHost + currentFolder + url;
        }
    }

    // copies all the properties to this object
    var properties = ['host', 'hostname', 'hash', 'href', 'port', 'protocol', 'search'];
    for (var i = 0, n = properties.length; i < n; i++) {
      this[properties[i]] = parser[properties[i]];
    }

    // pathname is special because IE takes the "/" of the starting of pathname
    this.pathname = (parser.pathname.charAt(0) !== "/" ? "/" : "") + parser.pathname;
}
```

Usage ([demo JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/tjL5ta7h/)):

```
var myUrl = new ParsedUrl("http://www.example.com:8080/path?query=123#fragment");
```

Result:

```
{
    hash: "#fragment"
    host: "www.example.com:8080"
    hostname: "www.example.com"
    href: "http://www.example.com:8080/path?query=123#fragment"
    pathname: "/path"
    port: "8080"
    protocol: "http:"
    search: "?query=123"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**For those looking for a modern solution that works in IE, Firefox, AND Chrome:**

**None of these solutions that use a hyperlink element will work the same in chrome.** If you pass an invalid (or blank) url to chrome, it will always return the host where the script is called from. So in IE you will get blank, whereas in Chrome you will get localhost (or whatever).

If you are trying to look at the referrer, this is deceitful. You will want to make sure that the host you get back was in the original url to deal with this:

```
    function getHostNameFromUrl(url) {
        // <summary>Parses the domain/host from a given url.</summary>
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;

        // Handle chrome which will default to domain where script is called from if invalid
        return url.indexOf(a.hostname) != -1 ? a.hostname : '';
    }
```

Comment: This is a very important thing to consider!

Comment: This completely breaks relative urls, though!

Answer (score 4):

The AngularJS way - fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PT5BG/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parse URL using AngularJS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-init="init()">

<h3>Parse URL using AngularJS</h3>

url: <input type="text" ng-model="url" value="" style="width:780px;">

<ul>
    <li>href = {{parser.href}}</li>
    <li>protocol = {{parser.protocol}}</li>
    <li>host = {{parser.host}}</li>
    <li>hostname = {{parser.hostname}}</li>
    <li>port = {{parser.port}}</li>
    <li>pathname = {{parser.pathname}}</li>
    <li>hash = {{parser.hash}}</li>
    <li>search = {{parser.search}}</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
function AppCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('url', function() {
        $scope.parser.href = $scope.url;
    });

    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.parser = document.createElement('a');
        $scope.url = window.location;
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will be more angular if you will use `$document` and `$window` services

Answer (score 4):

Expanded on acdcjunior solution by adding "**searchParam**" function
**Mimicking the URL object**, added "**searchParam**" to parse query string
Works for IE 6, 7, 8 9, 10, 11

**USAGE** - ([JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/CodeCowboyOrg/c1agph8y/4/))

```
// USAGE:
var myUrl = new ParsedUrl("http://www.example.com/path?var1=123&var2=abc#fragment");
console.log(myUrl);
console.log(myUrl.searchParam('var1'));
console.log(myUrl.searchParam('var2'));
```

**OUTPUT** - ([JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/CodeCowboyOrg/c1agph8y/4/))

```
{
  hash: "#fragment",
  host: "www.example.com:8080",
  hostname: "www.example.com",
  href: "http://www.example.com:8080/path?var1=123&amp;var2=abc#fragment",
  pathname: "/path",
  port: "80",
  protocol: "http:",
  search: "?var1=123&amp;var2=abc"
}

"123"
"abc"
```

**CODE** - ([JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/CodeCowboyOrg/c1agph8y/4/))

```
function ParsedUrl(url) {
    var parser = document.createElement("a");
    parser.href = url;
    
    // IE 8 and 9 dont load the attributes "protocol" and "host" in case the source URL
    // is just a pathname, that is, "/example" and not "http://www.example.com/example".
    parser.href = parser.href;
    
    // IE 7 and 6 wont load "protocol" and "host" even with the above workaround,
    // so we take the protocol/host from window.location and place them manually
    if (parser.host === "") {
        var newProtocolAndHost = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
        if (url.charAt(1) === "/") {
            parser.href = newProtocolAndHost + url;
        } else {
            // the regex gets everything up to the last "/"
            // /path/takesEverythingUpToAndIncludingTheLastForwardSlash/thisIsIgnored
            // "/" is inserted before because IE takes it of from pathname
            var currentFolder = ("/"+parser.pathname).match(/.*\//)[0];
            parser.href = newProtocolAndHost + currentFolder + url;
        }
    }
    
    // copies all the properties to this object
    var properties = ['host', 'hostname', 'hash', 'href', 'port', 'protocol', 'search'];
    for (var i = 0, n = properties.length; i < n; i++) {
      this[properties[i]] = parser[properties[i]];
    }
    
    // pathname is special because IE takes the "/" of the starting of pathname
    this.pathname = (parser.pathname.charAt(0) !== "/" ? "/" : "") + parser.pathname;
  
  //search Params
  this.searchParam =  function(variable) {
    var query = (this.search.indexOf('?') === 0) ? this.search.substr(1) : this.search;
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
    return '';
    };
}
```

Comment: 2021 answer: Use `new URL('your string url')` and you get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`parse_url()`](http://locutus.io/php/url/parse_url/) function from [Locutus](http://locutus.io/) project (former php.js).

Code:

```
parse_url('http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor');
```

Result:

```
{
  scheme: 'http',
  host: 'hostname',
  user: 'username',
  pass: 'password',
  path: '/path',
  query: 'arg=value',
  fragment: 'anchor'
}
```

Comment: that url didn't work for me, but i found it over here https://github.com/hirak/phpjs/blob/master/functions/url/parse_url.js

Comment: @StanQuinn, that is because php.js changed it's name to Locutus. I have updated my answer with new link.

Answer (score 3):

Simple and robust solution using the module pattern. This includes a fix for IE where the `pathname` does not always have a leading forward-slash (`/`).

I have created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ryankane/718566dba322a952ae9f) along with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/ded7zd0a/) which offers a more dynamic parser. I recommend you check it out and provide feedback.

```
var URLParser = (function (document) {
    var PROPS = 'protocol hostname host pathname port search hash href'.split(' ');
    var self = function (url) {
        this.aEl = document.createElement('a');
        this.parse(url);
    };
    self.prototype.parse = function (url) {
        this.aEl.href = url;
        if (this.aEl.host == "") {
           this.aEl.href = this.aEl.href;
        }
        PROPS.forEach(function (prop) {
            switch (prop) {
                case 'hash':
                    this[prop] = this.aEl[prop].substr(1);
                    break;
                default:
                    this[prop] = this.aEl[prop];
            }
        }, this);
        if (this.pathname.indexOf('/') !== 0) {
            this.pathname = '/' + this.pathname;
        }
        this.requestUri = this.pathname + this.search;
    };
    self.prototype.toObj = function () {
        var obj = {};
        PROPS.forEach(function (prop) {
            obj[prop] = this[prop];
        }, this);
        obj.requestUri = this.requestUri;
        return obj;
    };
    self.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.href;
    };
    return self;
})(document);
```

## Demo

```js
var URLParser = (function(document) {
  var PROPS = 'protocol hostname host pathname port search hash href'.split(' ');
  var self = function(url) {
    this.aEl = document.createElement('a');
    this.parse(url);
  };
  self.prototype.parse = function(url) {
    this.aEl.href = url;
    if (this.aEl.host == "") {
      this.aEl.href = this.aEl.href;
    }
    PROPS.forEach(function(prop) {
      switch (prop) {
        case 'hash':
          this[prop] = this.aEl[prop].substr(1);
          break;
        default:
          this[prop] = this.aEl[prop];
      }
    }, this);
    if (this.pathname.indexOf('/') !== 0) {
      this.pathname = '/' + this.pathname;
    }
    this.requestUri = this.pathname + this.search;
  };
  self.prototype.toObj = function() {
    var obj = {};
    PROPS.forEach(function(prop) {
      obj[prop] = this[prop];
    }, this);
    obj.requestUri = this.requestUri;
    return obj;
  };
  self.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.href;
  };
  return self;
})(document);

/* Main */
var out = document.getElementById('out');
var urls = [
  'https://www.example.org:5887/foo/bar?a=1&b=2#section-1',
  'ftp://www.files.com:22/folder?id=7'
];
var parser = new URLParser();
urls.forEach(function(url) {
  parser.parse(url);
  println(out, JSON.stringify(parser.toObj(), undefined, ' '), 0, '#0000A7');
});

/* Utility functions */
function print(el, text, bgColor, fgColor) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = text;
  span.style['backgroundColor'] = bgColor || '#FFFFFF';
  span.style['color'] = fgColor || '#000000';
  el.appendChild(span);
}
function println(el, text, bgColor, fgColor) {
  print(el, text, bgColor, fgColor);
  el.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}
span {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: thin solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
#out {
  display: block;
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

## Output

```
{
 "protocol": "https:",
 "hostname": "www.example.org",
 "host": "www.example.org:5887",
 "pathname": "/foo/bar",
 "port": "5887",
 "search": "?a=1&b=2",
 "hash": "section-1",
 "href": "https://www.example.org:5887/foo/bar?a=1&b=2#section-1",
 "requestUri": "/foo/bar?a=1&b=2"
}
{
 "protocol": "ftp:",
 "hostname": "www.files.com",
 "host": "www.files.com:22",
 "pathname": "/folder",
 "port": "22",
 "search": "?id=7",
 "hash": "",
 "href": "ftp://www.files.com:22/folder?id=7",
 "requestUri": "/folder?id=7"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/uri-parse-lib for this

```
var t = parserURI("http://user:pass@example.com:8080/directory/file.ext?query=1&next=4&sed=5#anchor");
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do not use it?

```
        $scope.get_location=function(url_str){
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href =url_str;//"http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";
        var info={
            protocol:parser.protocol,   
            hostname:parser.hostname, // => "example.com"
            port:parser.port,     // => "3000"
            pathname:parser.pathname, // => "/pathname/"
            search:parser.search,   // => "?search=test"
            hash:parser.hash,     // => "#hash"
            host:parser.host, // => "example.com:3000"      
        }
        return info;
    }
    alert( JSON.stringify( $scope.get_location("http://localhost:257/index.php/deploy/?asd=asd#asd"),null,4 ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop reinventing the wheel. Use https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/

```
var uri = new URI("http://example.org:80/foo/hello.html");
// get host
uri.host(); // returns string "example.org:80"
// set host
uri.host("example.org:80");
```

Comment: Because every time you want to solve a problem... use a library? Okay... (not)

Comment: Not always (actually almost never) but URLs are very tricky to parse, there are many many details in the RFCs. Better to use a library that has been used and tested by thousands.

Comment: How about just use what is built in, instead of having someone else reinvent the wheel with a library?   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006120/747739

Comment: There is no IE11 support for the built-in function, so this library is excellent. To say never to use a library is like saying we should never have used jQuery and just write native code, which is absolutely ridiculous. Every developer has a different use case, there is no 'best' way, sometimes vanilla/native works best, sometimes it doesn't... something 92% of developers still has to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Just use url.js library (for web and node.js).

https://github.com/websanova/js-url

```
url: http://example.com?param=test#param=again

url('?param'); // test
url('#param'); // again
url('protocol'); // http
url('port'); // 80
url('domain'); // example.com
url('tld'); // com

etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple hack with the first answer

```js
var getLocation = function(href=window.location.href) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = href;
    return l;
};
```

this can used even without argument to figure out the current hostname
**getLocation().hostname** will give current hostname

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't parse the query and hash, but otherwise it works well otherwise.

```js
const getURIParts = (url) => {
  const matches = url.match(/^(\w+?:\/\/)?([\w-\.]+(?=\/?))?:?(\d*)?([^:]*)/)
  return {
    scheme: matches ? matches[1] : undefined,
    host: matches ? matches[2] : '',
    port: matches ? matches[3] : undefined,
    pathname: matches ? matches[4] : ''
  }
}

console.log(getURIParts(""))
console.log(getURIParts("http://localhost/bla"))
console.log(getURIParts("https://api.spotify.com/"))
console.log(getURIParts("https://api.spotify.com"))
console.log(getURIParts("wss://wss.slack.com/link/?ticket=1234-5678"))
console.log(getURIParts("localhost"))
console.log(getURIParts("localhost/bla"))
console.log(getURIParts("localhost/"))
console.log(getURIParts("api.spotify.com/bla/two"))
console.log(getURIParts("api.spotify.com:8000/bla/two"))
console.log(getURIParts("https://api.spotify.com:8800/"))
console.log(getURIParts("/mp3-preview/f504e6b8e037771318656394f532dede4f9bcaea"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course in **>2016** the right answer is using [**URL API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
For page URL [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)
And for `<a href="...">` [`HTMLAnchorElement API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement)

Also for supporting older browser, using polyfill:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=URL"></script>
```

But just as an other option, it can be handle easy and accurate by **RegEx pattern**:

```js
function URIinfo(s) {
    s=s.match(/^(([^/]*?:)\/*((?:([^:]+):([^@]+)@)?([^/:]{2,}|\[[\w:]+])(:\d*)?(?=\/|$))?)?((.*?\/)?(([^/]*?)(\.[^/.]+?)?))(\?.*?)?(#.*)?$/);
    return {origin:s[1],protocol:s[2],host:s[3],username:s[4],password:s[5],hostname:s[6],port:s[7],path:s[8],folders:s[9],file:s[10],filename:s[11],fileext:s[12],search:s[13],hash:s[14]};
}

var sample='http://user:password@my.site.com:8080/onefolder/folder.name/file.min.js?query=http://my.site.com:8080/file.exe#hash-root:/file/1.txt';

console.log (URIinfo(sample));
/*
{
  "origin": "http://user:password@my.site.com:8080",
  "protocol": "http:",
  "host": "user:password@my.site.com:8080",
  "username": "user",
  "password": "password",
  "hostname": "my.site.com",
  "port": ":8080",
  "path": "/onefolder/folder.name/file.min.js",
  "folders": "/onefolder/folder.name/",
  "file": "file.min.js",
  "filename": "file.min",
  "fileext": ".js",
  "search": "?query=http://my.site.com:8080/file.exe",
  "hash": "#hash-root:/file/1.txt"
}
*/
```

Work with [**the RegEx**](https://regexr.com/6f3hb)

It is fine with any kind of

- Absolute / Relative paths
- IPv4 / [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address)
- Net protocols / Local Files
- Query / Hash

And will return all URL options but not [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

(+) Also will return **file info** like [PHP pathInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 0):

How about?

`'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript'.split('//').pop().split('/')[0]`

Resulting:

`'stackoverflow.com'`

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```js
function getUrlPath(str){
//fakepath when url not have a path
  var fakepath = "/FakPath";
  var url = str+fakepath;
  var reg = /.+?\:\/\/.+?(\/.+?)(?:#|\?|$)/;
  var output = reg.exec(url);
  // check "output" != null
  return (output) ? output[1].replace(fakepath,"") : fakepath;
}

var myurl = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/";
const path = getUrlPath(myurl);

console.log(   path     );
//output :  /questions/736513/
```