# Regex to match the URL last part with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some URLs and I like to catch the final part of the url.

My URLs are in the form of

```
http://www.my-site.dch/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Tulips.jpg
http://www.my-site.dch/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Tulips-150x200.jpg
http://www.my-site.dch/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Tulips-500x350.jpg
```

and what I like to catch is the /Tulips.......jpg

I have try that but with no luck

```
\/.*(-\d+x\d+)\.(jp(e)?g|png|gif)
```

Any better idea?

Comment: If you have to a lot of ULR manipulation and you'd like your code to be more readable, I recommend the excellent uri.js http://medialize.github.com/URI.js

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take a look at the `lastIndexOf` method:

```
var index = url.lastIndexOf("/");
var fileName = url.substr(index)
```

Comment: This is better then all above.

Comment: heads up, this solution does not work if url has parameters. i.e.: www.something.com/image.jpg?size=100x100 (upvoted because it is still a good solution for this question)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11664379/232175 for a nice library which handles more complex URIs (URI.js).

Answer (score 13):

The following regular expression will work:

```
/[^\/]+$/
```

Comment: This picks up the query string as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use this Regex:-

```
^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$
```

Get file name using `$6`

Answer (score 1):

`.*/(.*)` use this pattern and get the group 1.it will work I guess.
`.*` is a greedy regex so it will match until the **last** slash. After that in group 1 will be the last characters (what you need)

Comment: I think @winSharp93's answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all the images are jpg:

```
/.\/\S+\.jpg/
```

Otherwise, more generale:

```
/.\/\S+\.\w{2,3}/
```

That is:

```
. any char
\/ the slash before the file name
\S+ any non blank char to match the file name (at least one)
\. the file extension separator
jpg or \w{3,4} the file extension
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you came here looking to find the last part of the url even if the url ends with **`/`**
There's a solution which is simpler than any regex solution. Even though the question is regarding regex, I will add it because it does add some value here.

If the url was this `http://www.my-site.dch/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Tulips.jpg`

```
const url = 'http://www.my-site.dch/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Tulips.jpg'
const lastpart = url.split('/').filter(e => e).pop()
```

In this case, the last part would return the last part even if it ends with `/`
So, if you had a url like this

```
/services/mosquito-control/
```

and you wanted to catch `mosquito-control`, you would be do it with this.