# How to check if URL has a specific string at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I need to get an overlay to slide down based on what the URL has at the end of it.

If (URL has 'faq' at the end)
{
overlay comes down
}

How can you do that in jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Is your URL a string or do you mean the current page URL ?

Comment: sorry my mistake the URL is the actual page URL...

Comment: What does your URL looks like? To make it easier to figure a proper way

Comment: You should refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140324/parse-url-with-javascript

Comment: can you share a example of url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript

Comment: You should look at the answer from complex857 - it's the best one here

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your URL looks something like this `http://yourdomain.com/faq`, you could do something like this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var lastPart = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

if (lastPart === "faq") {
   // Show your overlay
}
```

This would make it possible to check for other endings and act on them as well.

**Update:**

To get it working, even if the URL has a trailing slash, you could create a function like this:

```
function getLastPart(url) {
    var parts = url.split("/");
    return (url.lastIndexOf('/') !== url.length - 1 
       ? parts[parts.length - 1]
       : parts[parts.length - 2]);
}
```

You could then call the function like `getLastPart(window.location.href)` to get the last part of the URL for the current page.

Here is a working example as well: http://jsfiddle.net/WuXHG/

*Disclaimer: If your URLs use hashes at the end, or a querystring, you would have to strip the from the URL first, for this script to work properly*

Comment: @Alex Correct, in that case it wouldn't work. Does your addresses always have a trailing /, or is it only some paths that have it?

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to use the window.location object for this with a regexp, something like this:

```
/faq$/.test(window.location)
```

If you want to match just the path regardless of query string or hash:

```
/faq$/.test(window.location.pathname)
```

Comment: To ignore parameters: /path\/to$/.test(window.location.pathname)

Answer (score 6):

A new method `endsWith()` has been added to the ES6 specification. For previous versions we can polyfill it using

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith)
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchStr, Position) {
      // This works much better than >= because
      // it compensates for NaN:
      if (!(Position < this.length))
        Position = this.length;
      else
        Position |= 0; // round position
      return this.substr(Position - searchStr.length,
                         searchStr.length) === searchStr;
  };
```

Now you can easily write

```
If (window.location.href.endsWith("faq")) { 
   // Show your overlay
}
```

**Reference:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current URL using :

```
 var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

Then you can use indexOf to check if your token is in the end of string (here faq)

```
 if (currentUrl.indexOf('faq') == currentUrl.length - 3)
 {
  // Do something here
 }
```