# How to get last element of url stripping out unwanted characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to capture the last element of the url and strip out any unwanted characters such as below

**http://www.myurl.com/abcs/der/er/..../asdsad/hrllo.shtml#header?query=whatever&....**

from the above URl, for example, I need to get only **hrllo**

```
var search_param = $(location).attr("href").split('/').pop().replace('#', '');
```

I think maybe a regex? the text hrllo can only have letters (capital or not).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140324/parse-url-with-javascript

Comment: Have you considered this really awesome and small URL parser: http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/ ?

Comment: Sorry Can not use any extra library...

Comment: Then copy/paste. it's a small utility with powerful features. Or use it as an example on how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query string contains dots or slashes, it should be removed first.

```
str.slice(0,str.indexOf('?'));
```

Otherwise, this one will be good enough.

```
str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1,str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: The problem with that is what if there is a `/` or `.` after the hash? `https://myurl.com/index3.html#query=twitter.com/search`

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting it at the hash instead, like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2d12s11/3/)):

```
var url = [
    "http://www.myurl.com/abcs/der/er/.../asdsad/hrllo1.shtml#header?query=whatever&....",
    "http://www.myurl.com/abcs/der/er/.../asdsad/hrllo2.shtml?query=whatever",
    "http://www.myurl.com/abcs/der/er/..../asdsad/hrllo3.shtml",
    "http://myurl.com/index3.html#query=twitter.com/search"
  ],
  i, left, index, page = [];
for (i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
  left = url[i].split(/[#?]/g)[0];
  index = left.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
  page.push(left.slice(index));
}

// result: page = [ 'hrllo1.shtml', 'hrllo2.shtml', 'hrllo3.shtml' ];
```

Comment: I can not always ensure there will be a hash!