# How slack web client parse URL and response the target URL image and text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

If I post a text includes an article URL to Slack chatroom then check Network requests with Chrome Network pane.
None of all the responses include parsed image URL and text.

I post a text `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140324/parse-url-with-javascript` on slack chatroom then I checked the responses data from Networks pane, there is no image URL or text. But slack web client knows what URL and text and showed them on the webpage.

[image: the first 3 response data not includes parsed image icon url and text, but the the 4th Request is <code>https://slack-imgs.com/?c=1&o1=wi32.he32.si&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.sstatic.net%2FSites%2Fstackoverflow%2Fimg%2Ffavicon.ico%3Fv%3D4f32ecc8f43d</code>]

How can slack web app knows the 4th request target URL `https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.sstatic.net%2FSites%2Fstackoverflow%2Fimg%2Ffavicon.ico%3Fv%3D4f32ecc8f43d` without the response from server?

Or there are some responses data I cannot know from the Network pane.

Answer (score 0):

It's on webscoket item !!

I didn't see it because of I clear the request items listed on Network pane for clear view.

After clear, I cannot see any data even websocket has already connected and receiving and sending data.

[image]