# javascript: get url path

Tags: javascript, regex, url

```
var url = 'http://domain.com/file.php?id=1';
```

or

```
var url = 'https://domain.us/file.php?id=1'
```

or

```
var url = 'domain.de/file.php?id=1';
```

or

```
var url = 'subdomain.domain.com/file.php?id=1'
```

from either one of these urls I want to get **only the path**, in the case above:

```
var path = '/file.php?id=1';
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You *could* do it with regex, but using these native properties are arguably the *best* way to do it.

```
var url = 'subdomain.domain.com/file.php?id=1',
    a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = 'http://' + url;
var path = a.pathname + a.search; // /file.php?id=1
```

[See it on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/4EJ7n/)

Comment: Great answer alex, but what if the url is like 'subdomain.domain.com/myfiles/file.php?id=1' and I just want to get the '/file.php?id=1', I should use regex, no?

Comment: @steweb In that case, get the path using the code above, and then [ditch the first segment with a regex](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/BdE8G/) `path.replace(/^\/[^\/]+/, '');`

Comment: Quite underestimated answer. It's brilliant.

Comment: Quite clever but only applies to browser environment. You couldn't run it in Node.js for example. Also it all comes down to string manipulation so employing a DOM element to do it is a bit awkward. I'm not downvoting, just saying ;)

Comment: @LucasPrus I certainly agree with you. It's handy to let the browser do the string manipulation for you, but luckily in Node I bet there is a heap of modules that already to this.

Answer (score 7):

In Douglas Crockford's book "JavaScript: The Good Parts", there's a regex for retreiving all url parts. It's on page 66 and you can see it here: http://books.google.ch/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA66

You can copy and paste from here: http://www.coderholic.com/javascript-the-good-parts/

Answer (score 2):

this version is with regex. Try this out:

```
var splittedURL = url.split(/\/+/g);
var path = "/"+splittedURL[splittedURL.length-1];
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you could use `splittedURL.pop()` to get the last member :)

Comment: Thanks a lot alex, I didn't know about pop() - wtf :)

Answer (score 0):

Use string.lastIndexOf(searchstring, start) instead of a regex. Then check if the index is within bounds and get substring from last slash to end of the string.