# Get filename from URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that grabs the filename from a URL but I have a problem.

Firstly, here's what I've got so far:

```
var img = $('img').attr('src'),
fileName_Index = img.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
    fileName = img.substr(fileName_Index);
```

If the URL was to have `?format=foo` after the filename, that part is added. Is there a way to remove the last part starting with the question mark leaving just the filename?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560618/break-a-url-into-its-components

Already asked

Comment: @Tezcat That question is about splitting up URLs in their entirety -- OP's needs are much more narrow and specific.

Comment: I agree with @Blazemonger, I've taken a look at that question although it seems very long winded for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line to the end of your code sample:

```
fileName = fileName.replace(/[\#\?].*$/,''); // strips hashes, too
```

[String.replace on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Is there no way to shorten it, say `fileName = img.substr(fileName_Index).replace(/[\#\?].*$/,'');`? Just wondering :)

Comment: Sure can. I was just trying to keep my answer simple.