# How to get hold of a part of dynamically generated URL

Tags: javascript

I'm using filestack, when ever I upload an image it creates an unique url for the uploaded Image. I want to get hold of a specific part of a url to a variable.

https://www.filestackapi.com/api/file/qiXTZ0dQUGPQRG4GH0Cy

https://www.filestackapi.com/api/file/"qiXTZ0dQUGPQRG4GH0Cy"

The above Url belongs to an image, but I want get hold of the quoted part to a variable, how to do that?

Comment: Split by `/` get last

Comment: Use regex `([^\]+$)` and get first captured group

Comment: Substring with `lastIndexOf`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get filename from URL using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468404/get-filename-from-url-using-javascript)

Comment: [Did you even try looking for an answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+filename+from+url) (746 results)

Answer (score 3):

You can search for the last index of `/` in the url then make a `substring` of the url starting from that point.

```
var url = 'https://www.filestackapi.com/api/file/qiXTZ0dQUGPQRG4GH0Cy';
var lastIndex = url.lastIndexOf("/");
var searched = url.substring(lastIndex + 1);

// searched = qiXTZ0dQUGPQRG4GH0Cy
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot.