# Add querystring parameters to YouTube URL in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I have a page that is created through a CMS that currently looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/id?start=1" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"  allow="autoplay"></iframe></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I've seen something similar to what I need but is there specifically a way that I can use a JS block so that anytime I have an iframe with a  youtube url, I can add "&autoplay=1&mute=1" to the source URL to get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/id?start=1&autoplay=1&mute=1" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"  allow="autoplay"></iframe></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is possible.  First, let's filter out all the iframes on your page by those we think have YouTube content.  For that, we'll use a RegEx on the URL.  (See also:  [Regex for youtube URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19377262/362536))

```
// RegEx Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704433/362536
const youtubeUrlPattern = /^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$/;
```

Next, we'll query for all the iframes, actually do the filtering.  Then, we'll edit the URL.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('iframe')].filter((iframeEl) => {
  // Filter to iframes loading YouTube URLs only.
    return iframeEl.src.match(youtubeUrlPattern);
}).forEach((iframeEl) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = iframeEl.src;
  a.search = a.search || '?'; // Ensure we have a minimal query string
  a.search += '&autoplay=1&mute=1'; // Naively concatenate our extra params.  (You may want to do more here, to see if they already exist.)
  iframeEl.src = a.href;
});
```

Note that I'm using an `a` element to do some of this URL parsing work for me.  (See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497576/362536).

I put up an example for you on a JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/3y251ued/

Answer (score 2):

In your script get your iframe elelment and then use .setAttribute()

```
let myFrame = document.getElementById('idOfMYFrame')
myFrame.setAttribute('mute': '1')
myFrame.setAttribute('autoplay' : '1')
```

You will probably need to do this within window.onload event.