# URL management facility?

Tags: javascript

Is there a (native) javascript API that offers the "functionality" of window.location to custom URLs? something along the lines of

```
var url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/question?hello=world#foo");
console.log(url.hostname, url.path);
// out: "stackoverflow.com", "/question"
url.hash = "bar";
url.query = "";
console.log(url);
// out: "http://stackoverflow.com/question#bar"
```

I'm fairly certain there is no native API for this (for what reason ever). If someone implemented this, please share the link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: @Cameron The questions may be similar, but the library that I linked to isn't there for example (and maybe other solutions as well).

Comment: @draevor: Yep, might be best to keep both (or have them merged, maybe).

Comment: Something made from scratch: http://jsfiddle.net/u7BD8/1/. Surely contains some bugs but it may be usable.

Comment: I'm not asking how to parse an URL. I was asking if there is a standard API I didn't know yet, or at least an opinion on some "standard" library to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer would be yes and no.

As some answer suggests, you could create an anchor element and use it to do the parsing, which is basically native code.

```
var url = document.createElement("A");
url.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/question?hello=world#foo";

console.log('// expected: "stackoverflow.com", "/question"');
console.log('//      got: "' + url.hostname + '", "' + url.pathname + '"');
output -->           got: "stackoverflow.com", "/question"

url.hash = "bar";
url.search = "";

console.log('// expected: "http://stackoverflow.com/question#bar"');
console.log('//      got: "' + url.href + '"');
output -->           got: "http://stackoverflow.com/question?#bar"
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/H48dt/

The only difference is, that the **?** is not removed after the querystring is emptied.

The "API":

```
url.protocol
url.host
url.port
url.pathname
url.search
url.hash
```

Comment: did not know that was possible, thanks. (Doesn't help much, though)

Answer (score 2):

Since there was no useful API for working with URLs, I built one myself: [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/).

It allows you to read/write components of an URL via a jQuery-like API and has some useful features for working with query strings, normalizing URLs and creating relative/absolute paths.

Merry Christmas, enjoy :)