# Remove protocol, domainame, domain and file extension from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

let say that in our websites we can have urls like:

```
http://domainame.com/dir/one-simple-name.html
https://dmainame.com/mail/send.php
https://dmainame.com/mail/read
```

etc..

So i would like to retrieve

```
dir/one-simple-name
mail/send
mail/read
```

Whats the best way to achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: @Brad that answer returns the extension again

Comment: If that answer doesn't meet your needs, try one of the 50 other duplicates, or ask on how to split a string by `.`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Everybody stand back! I know regular expressions!](http://xkcd.com/208/)
Try this one:

```
var my_location = window.location.toString().match(/\/\/[^\/]+\/([^\.]+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend doing this by,

```js
var url = "https://www.somegoodwebsite.com/happy/ending/results/index.html";
console.log(url.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '') );
```

;

```
Result:
happy/ending/results/index.html
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
var result = window.location.pathname.replace(/\.[^\.\/]+$/, "").substr(1);
```

In javascript, you can access the various parts of the URL via the [window.location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

```
window.location.href - the entire URL 
window.location.host - the hostname and port number - [www.sample.com]:80
window.location.hostname - the hostname - www.sample.com
window.location.pathname - just the path part - /search
window.location.search - the part of the URL after the ? symbol - ?q=demo
```

In your case, you can use `window.location.pathname` and then if you need to strip the file extension off the filename, you can do that with some additional javascript:

```
var result = window.location.pathname.replace(/\.[^\.\/]+$/, "").substr(1);
```

This line of javascript will get the pathname component of the URL and then replace any file extension with `""` (effectively removing it) and the remove the leading slash.

Comment: a = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180511/remove-protocol-domainame-domain-and-file-extension-from-url" 

"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180511/remove-protocol-domainame-domain-and-file-extension-from-url"

a.replace(/\.[^\.\/]+$/, "").substr(1);

"ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180511/remove-protocol-domainame-domain-and-file-extension-from-url"

Answer (score 0):

A more jqueryish way than using just regular expressions:

```
var path = $('<a>', {href: 'http://google.com/foo/bar.py'})[0].pathname.replace(/\.(.+)$/,'')
```

Comment: I tried this and got only a script error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"`.