# regex with 3 backreferences but one optional

Tags: regex, backreference

I have a regular expression that captures three backreferences though one (the 2nd) may be `null`.

Given the flowing string:

```
http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=site%3Ajonathonoat.es&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjonathonoat.es%2Fbritish-mozcast%2F&ei=MQj9UKejDYeS0QWruIHgDA&usg=AFQjCNHy1cDoWlIAwyj76wjiM6f2Rpd74w&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k,.co.uk,site%3Ajonathonoat.es&source=web,1
```

I wish to capture the TLD (in this case .co.uk), `q` param and `cd` param.

I'm using the following RegEx:

```
/.*\.google([a-z\.]*).*q=(.*[^&])?.*cd=(\d*).*/i
```

Which works except the 2nd backreference includes the other parameters upto the `cd` param, I current get this:

```
["http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=site%3Ajo…,d.d2k,.co.uk,site%3Ajonathonoat.es&source=web,1 ", ".co.uk", "site%3Ajonathonoat.es&source=web", "1", index: 0, input: "http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=site%3Ajo…,d.d2k,.co.uk,site%3Ajonathonoat.es&source=web,1"]
```

The 1st backreference is correct, it's `.co.uk` and so is the 3rd; it's `1`. I want the 2nd backreference to be either null (or undefined or whatever) or just the `q` param, in this example `site%3Ajonathonoat.es`. It currently includes the `source` param too (`site%3Ajonathonoat.es&source=web`).

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

I've added a [JSFiddle of the code, look in your browser console for the output](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathonoates/NLNXj/12/), thanks!

Comment: I'd also consider parsing the url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the middle group to be:

```
q=([^&]*)
```

This will capture characters other than ampersand. This also allows zero characters, so you can remove the optional group (`?`).

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/AJkXxgeX5K

Answer (score 1):

if negating character classes, i always add a multiplier to the class itself:

```
/.*\.google([a-z\.]*).*q=([^&]*?)?.*cd=(\d*).*/i
```

i also recoomend not using * or + as they are "greedy", always use *? or +? when you are going to find delimiters inside your string. For more on greedyness check J.F.Friedls Mastering Rgeular Expressions or simply [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)