# When parsing URL why is the A tag required?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I had a problem which required me to parse a URL so I could get the hostname/pathname of such URL, and use the pathname to compare it with a string.

(Answer can be found here: [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript))

The answer provided required to use DOM to create an element with the html tag A so one could access the url's pathname and hostname. My question is, why? Shouldn't the A tag be used to establish a link to another document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The A tag is not required, but convenient in this situation since the A tag already has functions to resolve the hostname and path.