# JavaScript - Parsing a URL into hostname

Tags: javascript, parsing

I was looking for a way to parse a given url into hostname, port and subdomian. I got a code like this from here : [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

but here "parser.href" is given a url. Instead of that, I have a user inputed JavaScirpt variable named 'q'. I need to send the value of variable 'q' into parser.href.   I tried to write simply as parser.href = q, but that didn't work.

Then I tried to implement the above as a function model through which I pass the variable q into it but that too didn't work. Here is the function:

```
  function parseUrl(url) {
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href = url;
      return(parser.hostname);
}

var host = parseUrl(q);
```

I thought after executing the function, variable "host" will have the hostname that is returned from the function but that also didn't work. Could some one tell me how can I modify this so that it works correctly ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It already works!

Checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamruss/g7dHa/)

```
function parseUrl(url) {
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = url;
  return(parser.hostname);
}

var host = parseUrl('http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash');
document.write(host);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/rFYYv/

```
   function parseUrl(url) {
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href = url;
      return(parser.hostname);
   }

var output = document.getElementById('output');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.onkeyup = function(e) {
    output.innerHTML = parseUrl(input.value);
};
```

Comment: Your fiddle always returns the answer "fiddle.jshell.net" no matter what the inout you gives right ? that is the same problem that I am facing. I am getting the hostname of the site in which I implement this instead of the hostname of the url saved in the javascript variable

Comment: No, it always gives the right hostname, if i copy this question's url, and paste it into the input, it says stackoverflow.com