# How to get url from string - jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have url like this  :

```
http://192.168.6.1/Images/Work3ererg.png
http://192.168.6.1/Images/WorwefewfewfefewfwekThumb.png
http://192.168.6.1/Images/ewfefewfewfewf23243.png
http://192.168.6.1/Images/freferfer455ggg.png
http://192.168.6.1/Images/regrgrger54654654.png
```

i would like to know `http://192.168.6.1` from those url...how can i achieve this using jquery or javascript?

what am i trying to do it :

```
i got this string from my JavaScript :  http://192.168.6.1/Images/Work3ererg.png
```

using this javscript string :

i want to put `**https://192.168.6.1/**` instead of `**http://localhost:37774**` including **http**

```
$("#" + id).css("background", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(http://localhost:37774/Images/PBexVerticalLine1.png) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box")
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: those are string as in my image source, i want to replce few image source using different image file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **RegularExpression** (pure JavaScript) to do this job 
for example you can use

```
var ip = ''; // will contain the ip address
var ips = [] // ips is an array  that will contain all the ip address

var url = 'http://192.168.6.1/Images/Work3ererg.png';

url.replace(/http:\/\/(.+?)\//,function(all,first){
            // first will be something like 192.168.6.1
            // while all  will be something like http://192.168.6.1
            ip = first;
});

// url can be a a list of ip address in this case we should add the 
// g flag(which means global, not just the first match but all the matches )


url  ='http://192.168.6.1/Images/Work3ererg.png';
url +='http://192.168.6.2/Images/Work3ererg.png';

url.replace(/http:\/\/(.+?)\//g,function(all,first){
           ips.push(first);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = 'http://192.168.6.1/Images/Work3ererg.png';
var host = url.substr(0,url.indexOf('/',7));
```

`url.indexOf('/',7)`means search `/` after `http://`

Then use `substr` to get string from start to the first `/` after `http://`

Answer (score 0):

If browser support (IE 10 and higher and recent browser), you could use the [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

You simply have to do that :

```
var test = new URL('http://192.168.6.1/Images/regrgrger54654654.png')
console.log(test.origin)
```

If you want to use a regular expression, that would do it for this case :

```
var url = 'http://192.168.6.1/Images/regrgrger54654654.png'

console.log(url.match(/https?:\/{2}[^\/]*/)[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cd67Lzs/

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/736970/1026017

```
var getHostname = function(href) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = href;
    return l.hostname;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace part of string with another string:

```
var originalString = "http://192.168.6.1/Images/freferfer455ggg.png";
var newString = originalString.replace("http://192.168.6.1/","https://192.168.6.1/");
console.log(newString);
```