# Internal Or External Link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small problem with my links. I am trying to have it so when a link is checked, It uses javascript to handle page loading, This is fine, But before it loads the page I want it to take the URL it passed to JavaScript and check if it is external, If it is, Then alert them, Else just continue... heres the code I have so far:

JavaScript Document:

```
function loadPage(page, tag, ext) {
    if (tag) {
        fadeOut(tag);
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (page) {
                console.log('Attempting To Buffer Next Page...');
            } else {
                console.log('ERROR: No Page To Buffer');
                return; 
            }
            if (ext) {
                console.log('Loading Custom Extension');    
                if (checkExternal(page) == true) {
                    window.location = "external.php?url="+page+"."+ext
                } 
                else {
                    window.location = page+"."+ext
                };
            } else {
                console.log("No Custom Extension, Using .hmtl");
                if (checkExternal(page) == true) {
                    window.location = "external.php?url="+page+".html"
                } else {
                    window.location = page+".html"
                };
            }
        }, 500);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("ERROR: Tag Field Empty, Cannot Load Page") 
    };
};
```

Html Link:

```
<a onclick="loadPage('https://github.com/hbomb79/securitySystemPro/issues', 'body');" class="url">GitHub</a>
```

I have tried other results on here, But they all check the href attribute, I need to check a URL passed to a function that returns true if its external.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: what is fadeOut(tag)?

Comment: That is a function that fades out the tag specifed using jQuery, So I basically pass the body tag to that so it fades out: http://www.harryfelton.host56.com/ Is my website where you can see this in effect.

Comment: Why -1? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comparing a click event's `.hostname` with `location.hostname` you can easily check if a link is still local.

In the code below I apply a `.click` event to the class `link` : Meaning many elements can use the `link` class to be included in the event handling.

I personally find it preferable to use this method as it requires no changes to the main HTML document. That being said, you could always use `onclick="function()"` and get the same results.

```js
 $(".link").click(
   function(e) {
     if (e.target.hostname === location.hostname) {
       console.log("going local")
       return true;
     } else if (confirm("Do you with to leave this website?")) {
       console.log("Leaving Website");
       return true;

     } else {
       console.log("Staying here");
      return false;
     }

   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <a class="link" href="http://somewebsite.com"> somewebsite.com </a>
  <a class="link" href="#"> # (local) </a>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, Well in my current code I am using an onclick event, Which passes the URL of the page, How would I check if that is external... Would it be something like this: `function checkExternal(url) {
     if (url.target.hostname === location.hostname) {
       console.log("Going local")
       return true;
     } else if (confirm("Do you with to leave this website?")) {
       console.log("Leaving Website");
       return true;

     } else {
       console.log("Staying here");
       return false;
     }
});`

And then just call this from the function in the main question?

-Thanks

Comment: By the way, the second link also asks for confirmation, even though it is local...

Comment: If you want to manually pass in the url, you will need a nasty looking regular expressions parse out the host name. The event handler does this automatically thus creating `target.hostname`, so that's another reason to use Jquery xP

Comment: The second answer here explains how to parse a url if you really don't want to use Jquery : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Comment: I removed the second link : I forgot that the code snippets are not actually hosted on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I want to use jQuery, I just don't know how, I'll check out the link anyways. I just want to be able to give it the url to check.

Comment: Using a function caller is not exactly best practices : if you are going down that road read url parser I linked

Comment: Thank you, I have done it, Here is the final code for anyone interested:

`function checkExternal(href) {
    var location = document.createElement("a");
    location.href = href;
    if (location.host == "") {
   console.log("Hostname Is Empty, Local Link");
      location.href = location.href;
    } else if (location.host == "www.harryfelton.host56.com") {
  console.log("Hostname Matches Current Domain, Assuming Local");
 } else {
  console.log("Hostname External");
  return true
 }
    return false;
};`

I simply call this from the JS function in the question.

Thanks

Comment: #1: overwriting location is a very bad idea, #2 hard coding your variables is not best practice either. Have you tried the code I supplied above?

Comment: What do you mean, Overwriting Location... I made small adjustments:

`function checkExternal(href) {
    var location = document.createElement("a");
    location.href = href;
    if (location.host == "") {
   console.log("Hostname Is Empty, Local Link");
      location.href = location.href;
    } else if (location.host == window.location.hostname) {
  console.log("Hostname Matches Current Domain, Assuming Local");
 } else {
  console.log("Hostname Of Url Doesnt Match: "+window.location.hostname);
  return true
 }
    return false;
};`

What code have you supplied, I looked at the link you gave

Comment: Yeah, But they arent href, they are calling a function so the page can transition correctly, So I have to use a function for that, It seems easier to me to just use a function rather than a seperate href tag. Anyways, Im happy with how it works, If I encounter issues then I shall reconsider