# How to get the domain name using regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have just started to use regular expression and I am finding it difficult to find a regular expression to get the main domain name, that is, if I have urls as given below..

```
url = http://blog.example.co.in/page/category=?order.php
url = https://www.example.co.ca?page.html
```

so out of this I want to get only the **example** out the urls given above. So how can i do it..!!If you can get **example** in any other method will also be helpful..

I myself tried some methods as given below..

```
var url = urls.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').replace('www.','').split(/[/?#]/)[0];
var out = url.split('.')[0];
```

in this I am able to get the output for

```
https://www.example.co.ca?page.html
```

but not for

```
url = http://blog.example.co.in/page/category=?order.php
```

so can someone help me out a method that can get **example** out of any kind url

thank you

Comment: Why use a regular expression http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Comment: "example" isn't the domain name. "example.co.in" or "example.co.ca" would be the domain name.

Comment: yea i know that..so can you atleast tell me how to get example.co.in or example.com.ca from the above urls

Comment: http://regexr.com/39cuo. RegExr is a great (FREE) resource and tester. I personally use a paid app from http://www.regexbuddy.com/, but he's got lots of great, free, tutorial resources at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: The issue with this example - getting the "main" domain when your top-level domain (TLD) has more than one "part" (don't know the technical terms) is you would need to have a list of all those types of TLDs so you're not just grabbing `/\.whatever$/` plus whatever is immediately before it. Your RegEx will have a hard time distinguishing if your domain is "co.in", "example.co.in" or "blog.example.co.in". That's why [this makes more sense](http://stackoverflow.com/a/736970/1128978) than using RegEx.