# Chrome extension webrequest.onBeforeRequest redirect xhr+https failed

Tags: ajax, redirect, google-chrome-extension, https, xmlhttprequest

I'm developing chrome extension that redirect javascript, css files to another host. But it's not working for https and xhr request. 
It works when if details.type is not xmlhttprequest;
I tried to add my listener on onHeadersReceived. But same error occured.

Error:

```
t=1824814 [st=0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=5]
t=1824814 [st=0]   +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=5]
t=1824814 [st=0]      DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=5]
                      --> delegate_info = "extension Redirect"
t=1824819 [st=5]      CHROME_EXTENSION_REDIRECTED_REQUEST
                      --> extension_id = "kgggbgffjdlccdflannojbfnabeecefm"
t=1824819 [st=5]   -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=1824819 [st=5]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=0]
                    --> load_flags = 737536 (BYPASS_DATA_REDUCTION_PROXY | IGNORE_LIMITS | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                    --> method = "GET"
                    --> priority = "HIGHEST"
                    --> url = "https://www.example.com/dojo/nls/dojo_mn-mn.js"
t=1824819 [st=5]      URL_REQUEST_REDIRECT_JOB
                      --> reason = "Delegate"
t=1824819 [st=5]      URL_REQUEST_FAKE_RESPONSE_HEADERS_CREATED
                      --> HTTP/1.1 307 Internal Redirect
                          Location: https://anotherexample.com/dojo/nls/dojo_mn-mn.js
                          Non-Authoritative-Reason: Delegate
t=1824819 [st=5]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=1824819 [st=5]      CANCELLED
t=1824819 [st=5]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                    --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=1824819 [st=5]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=1824819 [st=5] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

My code is:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details){
            var path=getLocation(details.url).pathname;
            if(!path.endsWith(".css")||path.endsWith(".js"))){
                return {cancel:false};
            }
            return {
                 redirect:"https://anotherexample.com"+path
            };
        },{urls: ["https://www.example.com/*"]},["blocking"]
    );
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to redirect all https requests of type "xmlhttprequest", nothing to do scripts or css, right?

Comment: What's your `getLocation`?

Comment: @Xan it looks like getLocation is taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)