# How to explode url in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My url (localhost) :

```
http://localhost/nana-appication/public/
```

or

```
http://localhost/nana-appication/public/home
```

My url (server) :

```
http://dsp.nana.com/public/
```

or

```
 http://dsp.nana.com/public/home
```

I want to eliminate :

Localhost : `http://localhost/nana-appication/`

Server : `http://dsp.nana.com/`

So when I run console.log or alerts in javascript, a result like this :

localhost or server :

```
public/
```

or

```
public/home
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = 'http://localhost/nana-appication/public/home';
var b = a.replace(a.split(/public.*/)[0],'');
console.log(b); // 'public/home'
```

(First you explode the string by '/public.*', then replace first part with empty string).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/a/736970/5741308
(which is brilliant).

Read down as a later answer addressed relative paths and IE strangeness.