# Redirecting from one index.html page to 2 urls

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I need to use javasctipt to redirect  to a URL

I currently use something like:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
 window.location="http://app1.mydomain.com/red";
</SCRIPT>
```

But now I need the redirect to be smart and go to a different executable based on the host.

Example

```
red.mydomain.com -->  http://app1.mydomain.com/red
blue.mydomain.com -->  http://app1.mydomain.com/blue
```

Further complicating matters I need the parameters to remain in tact.

```
blue.mydomain.com/?parameter1=abc?paramteter2=123 -->http://app1.mydomain.com/blue/?parameter1=abc?paramteter2=123
```

How does one "read" the in URL and do a case statement to branch it out?

How does one keep the paramter string so He can pass it in tact?

Comment: What is the question, what have you tried?

Comment: Simply parse it with a Regex and then switch the solutions you need. In order to answer at your edit  pls see : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: You don't use regex for URLs.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two Sub domains Red and Blue and then You will have

red.example.com
blue.example.com

Then In your .htacsess put in

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^red\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.red\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/red" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blue\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blue\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/blue" [R=301,L]
```

and now when someone now goes to red.mydomain.com they will be redirected to https://example.com/red before the page loads making the redirect faster than loading the page then redirecting them to then load another page.

- Remember to change the domain name when copying and also if you don't have a ssl change https:// to http:// on the last line of both of them.

I Hope this helps, Lewis

Comment: I usually do that, but in this case but I dont have access to .htacess

Comment: why is that? can you not just go into cpanel and then set up a redirect?

Comment: This is on a corporate server.   There are a lot of different server configurations in the world.  Many many of them  don't use "cpannel".  And many of them don't even use Apache.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: can you create the subdomains ?

Comment: Without going into the full topography of the network and the corporate security roadblocks......It needs to be done in Javascript