# Change backgroundcolor with javascript by getcurrent URL

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code:

```
    <script>
function changeColor(newColor) {
 var currentLocation = window.location.href;

 if (window.location.pathname == "/communication-negotiation-and-conflict- management/")
       document.getElementById("color_var").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";  

</script>

Course full:     <span style="color:white; display:inline-block;" id="color_var">63%       </span>
```

What I expect from the code is - function will change color of ID according the current url -so if the url is what I defineded (/communication-negotiation-and-conflict-management/) the ID (color_var) should change its background color.

I do not know why this is not working :-(

Comment: You should give the html corresponding to it. Much code helps in finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your code snippet is just incomplete, but it seems, that your function is missing the closing brackets.

Also, I can't see, where you're actually calling the function, maybe you should give a bit more context here!

Answer (score 0):

Ah,

this is the first time I write to stackoverflow. So it might be a bit confusing. Let me explain it.

I created a widget in my Wordpress site and I am trying to make easy javascript function to create "Color changer" according the url.

So lets say - I have this page http://europeansummerschool.com/course/communication-negotiation-and-conflict-management/

And this course is "63%" full - so I want it to background-color those 63% with blue color.

I rewrite the code now like this:

```
<script>

var currentLocation = window.location.href;

if (currentLocation == "http://europeansummerschool.com/course/communication-negotiation-and-conflict-management/")
document.getElementById("color_var").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";  

  </script>
Course full: <span style="color:white; display:inline-block;" id="color_var">63%</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment on this, due to lack of reputation, so I'll have to write another awnser..

You didn't really mention, if you're new code snippet is working or not, but I guess it isn't. The reason being, that your script tag is executed, before `#color_var` is added to the DOM. Therefore the element you're trying to retrieve by calling `getElementById()`isn't there yet.

Another source for errors could be, that you're comparing `window.location.href` to a String of the URL. If the URL varies just slightly, this won't work. For example if you're using https instead of http, or the url doesn't contain a trailing slash.

There a lot of different methods, to getting just the hostname and a lot of threads on SO. [Take a look at this, for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)