# Regular expression not working without www

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Below regular expression not working without www

```
 /((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)/i
```

I have checked below URLs

```
http://regexr.com       (working, match)
http://www.regexr.com/  (working, match)
www.regexr.com          (working, match)
regexr.com              (not working, should be match)
abc@gmail.com           (working, not match)
```

If i used below code

```
((?:https?\:\/\/|)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)
```

then it matched email id also

```
abc@gmail.com           (not working, should not match)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What are you trying to validate?

Comment: yes i am working url validation

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Comment: @rrauenza i have tried this regex ^(https?\:)\/\/(([^:\/?#]*)(?:\:([0-9]+))?)(\/[^?#]*)(\?[^#]*|)(#.*|)$ but it matched email also(abc@gmail.com) and not worked for url http://regexr.com

Comment: and what about this =>  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149

Comment: @xAqweRx i think it worked for me ^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$

Comment: @amallard yes it not should matched abc@gmail.com because it's email.

Comment: The regexp says that a match has to begin with either `https?://` or `www.`. They're not optional, so why should it work without `www`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below regular expression worked fine, more information [click here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

Worked because it match below Url's and not email id

http://regexr.com/

http://www.regexr.com/

https://regexr.com

https://www.regexr.com

www.regexr.com

regexr.com

abc@gmail.com (worked, it not match email id)

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3djj7)

Answer (score 1):

[Demo on regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3djj1)

```
(https?:\/\/)?\w+(\.\w+)+(\/\w+)*(\/\w+\.\w+)?(\?[\w%&=.]*)*(?=[^\w.?&%=])
```

try this,