# Take Content url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

url:
http://xxxxxx.com/video/view/12345

Can I take 12345 in the url using javascript?

Please help me

Comment: what's your criteria? will it be always after /view? will it be always the last part of the path?

Answer (score 1):

Use `RegExp`, `Array#match` and negative lookahead.

```js
var str = 'http://xxxxxx.com/video/view/12345';
    console.log(str.match(/(?!view\/)\d+/)[0]);
```

Comment: Duplicates all around. Perhaps find one and close?

Comment: @mplungjan There's no exact the same solution as mine, in the link you have provided. Also it's much easier than the methods mentioned there.

Comment: You mean this is harder? `window.location.href.split('/').pop()` - also you assume there is a view always - the duplicate just takes the last

Comment: @mplungjan Fine, but your solution will work only if that number is the last element in the url.

Comment: And yours only works if view is one but last - more versions here to play with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, it will work only if there's a `view` word preceding the number. But since it's a static url, coming from some video site, it will work without any problems. Seems like only this number at the end is dynamic.

Comment: If that is so, then `var num = str.split('/').pop()` is certainly simpler than a regex

Comment: @mplungjan But what if the site passes some params in url? Like `view/12345?cookies=true`.

Comment: `location.pathname.split('/').pop()`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your URL with the following code. Then just get the last part.

```js
var url = 'http://xxxxxx.com/video/view/12345';
var url_parts = url.replace(/\/\s*$/,'').split('/');
console.log(url_parts[url_parts.length - 1]); // last part
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this if you're sure that it'll always be in last:

```
var num = location.pathname.split('/').pop(); // "12345"
```

and further: `parseInt(num);`