# want to split a string after a certain word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

Here is my code:

```
var url="https://muijal-ip-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/apexpages/setup/viewApexPage.apexp?id=066415642TPaE";
```

In this string i need only

```
url="https://muijal-ip-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/"
```

i need string upto "com/" rest of the string should be removed.

Answer (score 4):

In modern browsers you can use [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Properties)

```js
var url=new URL("https://muijal-ip-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/apexpages/setup/viewApexPage.apexp?id=066415642TPaE");

console.log(url.origin)
```

For unsupported browsers [use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

use javascript split

```
url = url.split(".com");
url = url[0] + ".com";
```

That should leave you with the wanted string if the Url is well formed.

Comment: You also could check javascript [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `locate` then `substr` like this:

```
var url = url.substr(0, url.locate(".com"));
```

`locate` returns you the index of the string searched for and then `substr` will cut from the beginning until that index~

Answer (score 1):

Substring function should handle that nicely:

```js
function clipUrl(str, to, include) {
  if (include === void 0) {
    include = false;
  }
  return str.substr(0, str.indexOf(to) + (include ? to.length : 0));
}
console.log(clipUrl("https://muijal-ip-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/apexpages/setup/viewApexPage.apexp?id=066415642TPaE", ".com", true));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Properties) API (as suggested by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308829/1238344)) isn't available you can reliably use properties of the [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) interface as a workaround if you want to avoid using regular expressions.

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'https://muijal-ip-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/apexpages/setup/viewApexPage.apexp?id=066415642TPaE';
console.log(a.protocol + '//' + a.hostname);
```

Comment: Thats nice. I was trying to figure out how we used to do this before `URL`