# Shrinking URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, frontend, web-frontend

How can we shrink the URL in JavaScript:

for example if the link was like this, it should not extend after .com

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Expected Output:

> https://stackoverflow.com

Thanks for your time,

**Solution**:
I have used Regexp to shrink the url

```
const yourUrl = {your url goes here}  
const reConstructUrl = new RegExp(
      [
        "^(https?:)//", // protocol
        "(([^:/?#]*)(?::([0-9]+))?)", // host (hostname and port)
         '(/{0,1}[^?#]*)', // pathname
         '(\\?[^#]*|)', // search
         '(#.*|)$' // hash
      ].join("")
    )
const matchedUrl = yourUrl.match(reConstructUrl);
```

Now you can display only the part you want from the URL

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried shrinking using the length of the string and shrinking using letters but, if there is any way to shrink this using a string(like after .com) it could be better, or if you a have any suggestions I will try that also,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class to parse the URL and get the `origin`:

```js
const url = new URL('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');

console.log(url.origin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308829/7765316), you can do some thing like this

```js
const url = new URL('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
console.log(url.origin)
```