# Regex - Removing parts of URL path

Tags: javascript, regex

I am useless at Regex and I want to remove parts of a URL that are not always consistent.

The URL might be:

> www.test.com **/en/** restOfPath
>
> or
>
> www.test.com **/en/en_gb/** restOfPath

Then depending on the country values might change to:

> www.test.com **/es/** restOfPath
>
> or
>
> www.test.com **/es/es_es/** restOfPath

I am therefore looking to alway remove, the parts in bold, so that I can split the remained of the path, to create a logical naming that is language/location agnostic.

I am doing this as a work around to build out a data layer until the client can implement it properly when they launch their new website. I have managed to build an if else statement as a workaround which is a bit clunky but would like a cleaner solution.

Comment: Generally we want to help people who've been working on a solution to solve a problem. Have you tried a regex solution for this. If not maybe you should do some regex tutorials?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript guru, but if you follow the link above you'll see that there are already some libraries out there which can help you to parse a URL/URI.  I'd start by using those as much as possible, and only afterwards resort to using a regex.

Comment: i used to be useless at Regex as well. What helped me was experimenting with my problems on http://regexr.com/ until I found a solution that fit. Now I am not completely useless anymore.

Comment: You have to get and use list of all those language abbreviations, otherwise regex doesn't have them. `lan1(?:_X1)?|lan2(?:_X2)?|lan3(?:_X3)?| ..` , etc..

Comment: Thank you for the responses. @alex sorry if I was not clear on why I needed help, I was writing a temporary work around in a tech spec for a client to build a page name for analytics. The answer above does not solve my question and I have tried the two regex below but they don't seem to do it either. I built an if else statement as a work around, but it is a bit clumsy.

Comment: @RomanRock the regex I provided definitely matches the text in bold in your examples. See the example i provided in the link.
What exactly is it you can't get working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this will help you

```
(?:\/([a-z]{2})(?:\/([a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}))?)
```

This example is about to find first `/` with two alpha after that, and probably another `/` with `aa_AA` construction.

I got you code samples at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RQT4ie/1)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're after:

`\/.*(?=\/.*?)`

https://regex101.com/r/OZIseI/4

It uses a positive look ahead to exclude the last `/` from the match

[image]