# Check previous page URL contains a string, then add class to element on the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check the previous page URL a user has visited for a string, then apply an "active" class to an "a" tag on the current page using jQuery.

e.g. if a user's previous page url contains "new-york" and looks like 
 - "www.domain.com/new-york/", then on the current page I want to check for an "a" tag which contains "new-york" in the link, then add a class to this tag. I have about 20 different cities I need to check and add classes too.

Here is what code I have so far...

```
$("#cities a").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == document.referrer) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

I know document.referrer is the exact URL, how do I grab/check for a string from document.referrer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/736970/8621306).

```
//assuming referer url is http://example.com/prev
function getLocation(href) {
   var l = document.createElement("a");
   l.href = href;
   return l;
}

//get the pathname from the url----
var l = getLocation(document.referrer);
var pathname = l.pathname;//returns "/prev"

$('a').each(function () {
   var current_url = $(this).attr('href');
   if(current_url.indexOf(pathname) !== -1){
      $(this).addClass('visited');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieve in multiple ways.

1. `document.referrer.indexOf("new-york") > -1` 
2. `document.referrer.match(/new-york/)`

Above things will work for your case. But remember document.referrer will not have query string params. If in future you have any case for that, then you can save prev page URL in the [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) or [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).