# How to turn parameter in wordpress url into a value?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, parameters, postback

The link is:

```
https://example.com/c=aj32mnir09sc0w983nm4ik34ld83ndi3
```

`c= a 32` is unique digit identifier code for s2s postback tracking.

I need to turn 'c' into a value. The wordpress site has a infusionsoft opt-in form and I am trying to append the 32 digit code to a lead that opts into the form. The form can add a value to the lead.

What is the best way to turn the c= parameter into a value. I can run javascript on my wordpress page, but everything I've found online and tried didn't do the trick. Is there a way to display on the page the value so I can see it on the page to see if it's generating the value correctly

Comment: i think you can parse it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript and than regex the "c="

Comment: Would be nice if you mentioned/linked the solutions you found and didn't work

Comment: That c parameter in the URL isn't `?c=`?