# Twig parse url to get ID for youtube embed

Tags: javascript, php, embed

I need to get the ID of a youtube video to dynamically embed the video in my webpage.

I am looking for a way to achieve the following in `twig`:

```
$url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqDT5_4z_YI"

parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );

echo $my_array_of_vars['v'];    

 // Output: hqDT5_4z_YI
```

Is this even possible or should I use `JavaScript` to do this?

Comment: yes but via link (`<a>`) object 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979390/2904507

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript:

```
let testparams = new URL("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqDT5_4z_YI").searchParams;
alert(testparams.get('v'));
```

Comment: That works! But I ended up going for this solution : `{{% set url = block.blogContentVideo|split('v=', 2) %}` Could you tell me if this is a good way to do it?

Comment: Oh, I don't know about your language!