# How can I make a page that look for URL and create a text that refer to the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

So it's kind of a dumb question but I'm really wondering how I can make this :

- user type www.mydomaine.com/something
- page display : something

and it does with anything he type  after the domain name

I've no idea how I could do that. I know I can get an info from an URL with jQuery but how can i remove the thing like index.html in the url? My guess would be with the htaccess?

Also, there won't be any other page but this with some design, how can I make sure someone doesn't go anywhere else but on the page that display what he wrote after the domain name?

I hope that's clear, thanks for reading and your answers !
Pierre

Comment: Are you limited to vanilla?

Comment: check out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

Comment: @Miaan No I'm not, I can also use jQuery

Comment: @errand Thank you! I'll check right now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an anchor tag and adding an href (or making a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)) I needed the URL to have a protocol (http or https), so I made a validation to add it, and then you can access the parameters of the URL easier.

Also, if you want to remove the `/` from the pathname you can use a `.replace('/', '')` when using `parser.pathname`

For removing index.html from the URL, you can split the path and get only the first element, or the ones you need f.e. `parser.pathname.split('/')[0]`

```js
var myUrl = "www.mydomaine.com/something"
if (!myUrl.startsWith('http')) myUrl = 'http://' + myUrl;

var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = myUrl;
console.log(parser.pathname);

// Other option
var theUrl = new URL(myUrl);
console.log(theUrl.pathname);
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979390/9801177) as a reference.