# replace in javascript to cut off part of string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this string, how can I make it until .html?

string

```
https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/fujitsu-standard-aa-rechargeable-battery-2000mah-4pcs-i237968048-s311807989.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.47.7f1a484d4gpCFd&search=1
```

make it into

```
https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/fujitsu-standard-aa-rechargeable-battery-2000mah-4pcs-i237968048-s311807989.html
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @CertainPerformance but I have no clue how to start?

Comment: Check [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: Michael, it is not appropriate to suddenly change the scope of your question. Now all of those answers are invalid.

Comment: @KarelG ok then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this example:

```js
var str = 'https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/fujitsu-standard-aa-rechargeable-battery-2000mah-4pcs-i237968048-s311807989.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.47.7f1a484d4gpCFd&search=1';

console.log(str.match('^.+\.html')[0]);
```

I've used regex with the pattern `^.+\.html` to match the url. The regex means: From the beginning of the string to `.html`

---

If you want to split the url to 2 parts, you could try:

```js
var str = 'https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/fujitsu-standard-aa-rechargeable-battery-2000mah-4pcs-i237968048-s311807989.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.47.7f1a484d4gpCFd&search=1';

var parts = str.split(/\?/);

console.log(parts[0]);
console.log('?' + parts[1]);
```

Comment: There is a reason why there is something called as [`URL API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) I rather prefer to see users using this instead of that regex route because this answer is not useful if you have to include other extensions as well (eg `.php` or `.asp`).

Comment: what I have other string around the url? then it should catch the https as prefix, also how do I replace it?, I don't want to print out the url only, I want the entire text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
var url =  "https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/fujitsu-standard-aa-rechargeable-battery-2000mah-4pcs-i237968048-s311807989.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.47.7f1a484d4gpCFd&search=1";


console.log(url.split('?', 1)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`URL` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL):

```
var url = new URL(string);
url.search = "";
url.hash = "";
return url.href;
```

Comment: nice but what is the next step? I want to replace the cleaned url back into its location.

Comment: @Micheal What do you mean by "its location"? You had a string for the url, right? Now you have the new url string.

Comment: sorry updated my question just now. It's not only the string, the urls are within a document string.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine according to your requirment

```
let url = "https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/fujitsu-standard-aa-rechargeable- 
         battery-2000mah-4pcs-i237968048-s311807989.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.47.7f1a484d4gpCFd&search=1"


url.substring(0, <nbsp> url.indexOf('.html')<nbsp> + <nbsp>5)
```