# Chrome Ext: Javascript interrogate URL string for hostname

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

> Note. This is not interrogate the url that you get from `window.location`

I am using the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` which returns details. These details are:

```
{
    frameId: 0,
    method: "GET",
    parentFrameId: -1,
    requestId: "687379",
    tabId: 1721765993,
    timeStamp: 1543573944865.511,
    type: "main_frame",
    url: "https://stackoverflow.com"
}
```

which means that the only URL I can get it from using `details.url` which is a string in the return. In this example it is:

> url: "https://stackoverflow.com"

I want to be able to get the hostname only:

> stackoverflow.com

The problem arises when there is https or http. If there is a subdomain or if there is extra paths.

How do I get only the hostname?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a neat little trick I use:

```
function processUrl(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a.hostname;
```

}

and then pass in your `details.url` to that function.

This creates an element and the browser engine processes the a element and works out your hostname etc. So you can return `a.hostname`.

### Edit

As mentioned below, this might be a little outdated. Another great solution is:

```
function processUrl(url) {
    return new URL(url).hostname
}
```

Comment: @wOxxOm - Great reply :) Added it to the answer. And yeah a little outdated - I just kept using it because it worked haha. Thanks for the update to my knowledge :)