# regex URL extract slash

Tags: regex

I need to extract the middle number from this using regex:

```
/166012342170/934760332134/794294808150/2436280815794/
```

Needed output: `934760332134`

I tried using this: `(?:.+?/){2}`

I am new to regex :(

Comment: Your needed output is not present in the input string.

Comment: Typo! sorry. Fixed

Comment: See `^/[^/]+/\K[^/]+` at https://regex101.com/r/z2Pztw/1

Comment: Or use a capturing group `^/\d+/(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/dzMrXh/1

Comment: I am using javascript flavor in my program so its not running. Any quick advice what i need to change.  https://www.regextester.com/97910

Comment: If this is actually a URL, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006120/2928853) answer, extract `pathname` from the URL, and then split on `/` character. No need for a complicated regex really.

Comment: In JS, you may even use `s.split("/")[2]`. Or, if you still want regex, `var m = s.match(/^\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)/); if (m) console.log(m[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

In JS, you may simply split the string with `/` char:

```js
console.log('/166012342170/934760332134/794294808150/2436280815794/'.split('/')[2])
```

If you plan to use regex you may use

```js
var s = '/166012342170/934760332134/794294808150/2436280815794/';
var m = s.match(/^\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)/); 
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `[^\/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([^\/]+)` - Capturing group 1: 1+ chars other than `/`

Answer (score 0):

To get that second number, the regex would be

```
(?:\/([0-9]+)){2}
```

which gives **934760332134** from the line below,

```
/166012342170/934760332134/794294808150/2436280815794
```

Try it on [here](https://regex101.com/r/B2sTps/1).