# Extract first /part/ of url with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to make regex which will extract this first part of url `/adjusterAnalytics/`?

Extract without `slash`.

http://192.168.15.122:3000/adjusterAnalytics/individual/Xh7HTIgGw1RqnsK2TuJtiUIMahy2

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Did you try anything ? Where's your attempt ?

Comment: You can refer this [URL API MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: @CodeManiac I like your solution

Comment: Of course you can do this with regex. But there are way better tools available to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is way to extract the required part by using negative [look-behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a [lazy quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```js
const [,match] = "http://192.168.15.122:3000/adjusterAnalytics/individual/Xh7HTIgGw1RqnsK2TuJtiUIMahy2".match(/(?<![\/:])\/(.*?)\//);

console.log(match)
```

Answer (score 1):

I overcomplicated it probably, but I made this regex for you

```
(?<schema>[a-z]+):\/\/(?<domain>[^:/]+)(?<port>:[0-9]+)\/(?<theFirstPart>[\w]+)\/.*
```

Usage within js:

```js
const regex = /(?<schema>[a-z]+):\/\/(?<domain>[^:/]+)(?<port>:[0-9]+)\/(?<theFirstPart>[\w]+)\/.*/gm;
const str = `http://192.168.15.122:3000/adjusterAnalytics/individual/Xh7HTIgGw1RqnsK2TuJtiUIMahy2`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
// This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
}

// The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
});
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/IU2Ms0/2