# How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript

Tags: javascript, file

How can I get the path name from the below URL?

```
file:///index.html/temp/data
```

I understand that `/temp/data` is the pathname.

`window.location.pathname` gives me `index.html/temp/data`

Comment: Try using `.split` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: I would create an `a` add it as `href` and use the properties given (pathname, hostname, host).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: What `window.location.pathname` gives you **is** the path name. `index.html` is part of the path, it isn't the hostname. (The hostname is the bit which goes between `//` and `/` and is blank for your file scheme URL).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if your url is file:///index.html/temp/data then the pathname will be everything after file://, so in your case it should return /index.html/temp/data.

I don't think there is a build in solution to handle this.

To solve the problem above you can try to do

```
window.location.pathname.split('.html/')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp.match` to get the desired path

```js
let [path] = 'index.html/temp/data'.match(/(\/\w*)+/);
console.log(path)

let [path2] = 'index.htm/temp/data'.match(/(\/\w*)+/);
console.log(path2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log (new URL("file:///index.html/temp/data")).
```

This will log an object with various properties such as `hostname` and `pathname` which I think is what you looking for.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

If that is the page you have loaded, you should be able to use
[`location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) to give you the path.

Otherwise, if that is just a string you have `string.split('/')[3]` but you should probably do some validation to make sure it is always after the 4th '/'

Comment: No, It didnt give me the path name, it returned me `index.html/temp/data`. If my URL is 
http://localhost:8080/temp/data then `window.location.pathname` gave me `/temp/data`

Comment: @PraveerKumar I just revised my answer

Comment: @PraveerKumar — In the question you claimed that `window.location.pathname` gave you `index.html`, now you claim it gives you `index.html/temp/data`. Which is it?