# Javascript parse URL as parameter for $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to parse an **URL as paramter** together with multiple **others** in my frontend to send a **JSON request to my Django backend**, but I receive the well known 404 error - not found.

**Django urls.py path:**

```
path("updateAssignment/<iD>/<body>/<deadline>/<user>/<url>/<game>/<aK>/<seoTitle>/<payment>/<wordCount>/<category>/<state>/", Dashboard.update_assignment, name="updateAssignment")
```

**Javascript $.getJSON Request**

```
function updateAssignment(assignmentId){

const assignmentUpdateEndpoint = "/updateAssignment/";



let body =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-Body"+assignmentId).value);
let deadline =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-Deadline"+assignmentId).value);
let user =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-User"+assignmentId).value);
let url =   encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-URL"+assignmentId).value);
let game =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-Game"+assignmentId).value);
let additionalKeywords =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-Additional-Keywords"+assignmentId).value);
let seoTitle =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-SEOtitle"+assignmentId).value);
let payment =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-Payment"+assignmentId).value);
let wordCount =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-WordCount"+assignmentId).value);
let category =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-Category"+assignmentId).value);
let state =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Assignment-State"+assignmentId).value);
assignmentId = encodeURIComponent(assignmentId);

let reqUrl = assignmentUpdateEndpoint +  assignmentId + "/" + body + "/" + deadline +"/" + user + "/" + url + "/" + game + "/" + additionalKeywords + "/" + seoTitle + "/"  + payment + "/" +  wordCount + "/" + category + "/" + state + "/";

$.getJSON(reqUrl).done((response) => {
    
});
```

The request only throws an error when **a real URL gets parsed**, thus the issue must related to it & how it gets encoded I guess. Help would be great.

Comment: @Taplar right, I've added my previous code now and I can guarantee that the strings parsed are not empty. It only throws an error when I parse an URL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Comment: What browsers are you testing on?  Try using console.debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using $.ajax instead of $.getJSON.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: endpoint,
  data: {},
  sucess: (response) => {
    
  }});
```

transmits the data in the right format to the server.