# Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: SharedArrayBuffer

Tags: react-native, expo, supabase, sharedarraybuffer

I'm starting my react-native project using expo in the iOS version and getting this obscure error which is blocking development progress. I've only started to see this error after trying to setup the supabase.js package and trying to setup the library against my supabase instance running locally via the supabase-cli.

I'm also polyfilling the URL package using `react-native-url-polyfill/auto`. If I do not polyfill the URL library, I see another error on startup that says `Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: URL`. You can see even supabase provides it in their own [documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-expo#launch).

I'm at my wits end and would like some direction on how to move forward so that I can continue building my application.

Below is a sample of the typescript file that's triggering this error:

```
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import {Database} from "../../lib/supabase/database.types";
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'

interface CreateUserOpts {
  name: string;
  username: string;
  phone: string;
  password: string;
}

const supabaseUrl = "http://localhost:54321";
const supabaseAnonKey = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJleHAiOjE5ODM4MTI5OTZ9.CRXP1A7WOeoJeXxjNni43kdQwgnWNReilDMblYTn_I0";

const client = createClient<Database>(
  supabaseUrl,
  supabaseAnonKey,
  {
      auth: {
        detectSessionInUrl: false
    }
  }
)

export const createUser = async (opts: CreateUserOpts) => {
  const {phone, password, ...additionalOpts} = opts;
  
  return client.auth.signUp({
    password: password,
    phone: phone,
    options: {
      data: {
        ...additionalOpts
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Having the same issue with react-native-url-polyfill

Comment: Just responded to the post for visibility. I hope the solution that worked for me points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this issue out. It was largely caused by using lerna+yarn and not bootstrapping my application appropriately for the expo runtime environment.

I landed on using a dependency called "expo-yarn-workspaces" to handle this for me. You can check out the configuration provided in this [readme](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-yarn-workspaces).

Comment: Thanks for the response @tscafie. I just needed the polyfill to parse url strings for their origin, so I went with a pure JS approach using regexes from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553982/797705