# How To Get UserName from url?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a username from a URL like  "example.com/u/AbcUser".
I know we can get it by using HTTP GET request, But I want to create a regular latest site

is it possible with Vanilla JS and HTML ??

Comment: Simply [parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/736513)?

Comment: `url.split('/').pop()` ..?

Comment: BTW i am using Firebase's host services,  will it throw an error of no page found ?

Comment: How can a user login or open a page if a page is not found? If a page is not found, then JS wouldn't start in the first place as it is never requested in that case...

Comment: @tacoshy yaaa , That Is my concern , I created a profile page then the user will input the URL like ** example.com/profile/AbcUser **  then Firebase will find and go to AbcUser not Profile page right?

Answer (score 1):

```
const url = window.location.pathname
const userName = url.split("/")[2]
```

Comment: How would this work with an URL like `http://example.com/u/AbcUser` ..?

Comment: window.location.pathname will get the path name after base url "/u/AbcUser"
url.split("/") will split the string on places where "/" is present ["", "u", "AbcUser"]
now you just use [2] index to get the user name "AbcUser"

Comment: Yes, but OP never stated that they use `location` to get the URL, they say (in a comment) that it is a user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <h1 id="wel" style="text-align: center; size: 25;"> </h1>
`enter code here` function getUserName(){
    var url = location.href;
    var spliting =url.split("?");

    var splitUser = spliting[1].split("&");

    var userNam= splitUser[0].split("=");


   return document.getElementById('wel').innerHTML = "Welcome :  &nbsp; "+userNam[0];

    }

    getUserName();
```

Comment: this code working good

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).